# Insurer that covers medevac repatriation from Cape Verde

Tags: health, insurance, cape-verde

I am soon traveling to Cape Verde where I am planning to do some hiking.

My country origin (Spain) gives travel advice, which states that an insurance supporting air medevac back home is recommended. I've checked several insurance companies (googled some, and other came from recommendations from other travelers' blogs) and none of them supports this.

They cover medevac using specially fitted aircraft but only from some countries, being European countries and non-European ones that border the Mediterranean Sea the coverage I've seen the most. The rest of countries are covered via commercial airlines. Although it's unlikely, I'm concerned about having to pay a medevac aircraft by myself if required, which I've read can cost around 50,000€.

What would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you believe that you need a private plane and can't be transported on a commercial airliner?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It's far from unheard of that if you are seriously sick or injured you are medevaced home. If so it needs to be a special flight because you can't get monitoring or medical treatment by a doctor when on a scheduled flight.

Comment: @DJClayworth I am not questioning the need for medevac, but why it can't be done on a scheduled flight. And your assumption is wrong. You can also be monitored and get supervision on regular flights. I know because I have been on such a flight. If I remember correctly and from what I could see, 4-5 rows at the rear of the plane were used for this purpose. On one side of the aisle, all back rests were tilted forward, so that they made a flat surface, on which a stretcher/bed with the patient was mounted while accompanying medical staff were sitting on the other side of the aisle.

Comment: Thanks you both for your contributions. @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, your feedback is specially interesting and it appeases me as I thought that such a solution _might_ be possible but I was not entirely sure. I'm still looking forward for having the option I asked for but it's good to know that there is an alternative. Thanks again.

Comment: @JesúsP. I can just speculate, but I assume that the countries where you may be picked up with a dedicated ambulance plane is limited to the plane's practical range. Ambulance planes are usually smaller aircrafts not built for longer flights, they may not even be approved for ocean crossings and even with intermediate fueling stops, longer distances will require multiple flight crews, which again would somehow have to be transported separately. There are lots of problems heaping up to give you what you think you need.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Medivac planes go around the world, no problem at all. They are like the very common private jets. In Switzerland we have a non-profit organization which do that (REGA) and they have no problem for long flights. On an airline is not much cheaper (but REGA will organize that providing equipment and personal), and more complex if change of flight is required (medicament between customs).